# php mail - include a html file in the mail

Tags: php

I have a mailer template in html format. It is a large html file with inline css that will hold dynamic data.

Now this is my code.

```
$subject = "V-Link Logistics Booking Update";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $msg = "mails/airbill.php";
    mail($res['0']['user_email'],$subject,$msg,$headers);
```

This does not seem to work and really dont get the problem. Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Does `airbill.php` have actual PHP code that needs to be executed?

Comment: no, it is just html and css .There is no query execution.

Comment: PHP's built in `mail()` function sucks. If you're doing anything beyond sending a basic plain text email to yourself as a site admin, you should be using a wrapper class like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. Either of these classes will make your life easy. Trying to use the `mail()` function on its own will lead you to misery. In all seriousness, download PHPMailer now. Don't even attempt to continue this using PHP's `mail()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PHP function `file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to simply extract the contents of a file.

So your `$msg` variable would be built like this:

```
$msg = file_get_contents("mails/airbill.php");
```

If `airbill.php` needs to be passed through the PHP interpreter, you could use the `include()` function's return value (which is the evaluated code). To use this method, the `airbill.php` file needs to actually return it's content as a string (using a simple return statement). So you could do something like this:

airbill.php :

```
<?php

$message = <<<message
<strong>This</strong> is the content of the <span style="...">email</span>
message;
return $message;

?>
```

Your other file would look like this:

```
$interpreted_content = include("mails/airbill.php")
$msg = $interpreted_content;
```

Comment: readfile() will also output the content of the file without using any echo or print function. use file_get_contents() instead

Comment: Nope. readfile() sends the output directly to the client and the content is never stored on the serverside (only when you habe OB turned on).

Comment: @chr - Yes, someone already pointed that out. I've already made the relevant edits.